# Python inheritance : change parent attribute in child class and use it in a method in parent class

Tags: python-3.x, oop, inheritance

I have a parent class that has an attribute kids=2. The attribute changes in the child class. The parent class has a method that uses that attribute, I want the method to give different results under the child using the updated attribute without redefining the method in the child class.

EXAMPLE BELOW :

```
class Parent:

   Kids=2
   def family_number (self, kids= Kids):
       Return kids+2

class child(parent):
   Kids = 3
```

I want child.family_number to pass in kids= 3, but it instead uses 2 as the default value.

How do I change what’s passed into the method using the child class.

I tried **init** and super() but that’s not the way I want to do it as I am not looking to make instance attributes. Is it possible to pass in the updated attribute to the inherited method without having to restate the method in the child class?

Comment: The value returned by `family_member()` has nothing to do with attributes at all - it's just the value of the method's default parameter, which was set at the time the function was defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the child class to use the updated attribute Kids without redefining the method, you can do this by accessing the attribute directly within the method in the parent class without passing it as an argument. Like this:

```
class Parent:
    Kids = 2

    def family_number(self):
        return self.Kids + 2

class Child(Parent):
    Kids = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Default arguments are looked up only when the function is compiled, not when it's called. That means that `Kids` only gets read once, when the `family_number` method is being compiled in `Parent`. The fact that a subclass gives it a different value doesn't matter, as the method never looks the attribute up when it's called, it just uses the saved default.

I'd suggest not using a default value here. Instead, lookup `self.Kids` in the method:

```
def family_number(self):
    return self.Kids
```